# Zend Framework - Best Way To Autoload From /Application/Api Folder

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to autoload Classes from within a folder contained in the application itself.

E.G.

```
/Application
    |->Models
    |->Custom
      |->Object.php
```

Is this the best way to do it (from bootstrap.php)?

> ```
> public function _initAutoLoad()
> {
>     $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
>         'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
>         'namespace' => '',
>         'resourceTypes' => array(
>                 'custom' => array(
>                     'path'      => 'custom/',
>                     'namespace' => 'Custom',
>                 ))
>     ));
> }
> ```

Meaning from within any controller, I can call:

> $object = new Custom_Object();

Comment: Yes, I think that's one of the better ways of going about it.

Comment: Accepted this as it appears to be the best method I can find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution I had is the best... I can find anyways...

Answer (score 2):

If you're not intending to prefix the class names with the application namespace (default `Application`), I'd simply put this stuff in `library`, eg

```
library/
    Custom/
        Object.php -> class Custom_Object
```

then add your `Custom` namespace to the autoloader in configuration (`application.ini`)

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Custom_"
```

---

If your class represents some kind of *service*, you could use the built-in `Service` resource type which is automatically autoloaded

```
application/
    services/
        Object.php -> class Application_Service_Object
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm aware of that method but the code is for an Api 'Service Layer' so not really something I think should sit in the 'Library' folder.

Comment: @Sjwdavies why not? Also, you could use the `Service` resource type. I'll update my answer to include this

Comment: I thought it would make sense as all internal db calls would be going through it? What is the Service resource?

Comment: It's really whatever you want it to be. Keep in mind these things are just names. I only mention these options as alternatives to your own as they are much simpler. I've seen plenty of problems attempting to get the resource autoloader working with an empty namespace